# file upload convert string data to json data javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Im loading a json data file and the data is read as a string. Im trying to convert that string into a JSON object using JSON.parse but its still the string..

THis is the JSON file

```
{
    "annotations": {
        "a": [{
                "AA00": [4.9724, 6.7862, 1.568737, 4.9943, 17.4203, 1.568737]
            },
            {
                "AA01": [6.5117, 17.4155, -1.572977, 6.5584, 6.7322, -1.572977]
            },
            {
                "AA02": [7.7934, 6.7196, 1.575093, 7.7473, 17.4463, 1.575093]
            },
            {
                "AA03": [9.7196, 17.3718, -1.563688, 9.7145, 9.6473, -1.563688]
            },
            {
                "AA04": [12.2965, 24.9181, -1.558673, 12.4939, 11.9399, -1.558673]
            }
                ]
                    ,
            "p": [{"HOME": [9.60, 6.22, 0.0]}]
        }

}
```

jquery code;-

```
$('#annotation-file-upload').on('change', function(){
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {      
                console.log(typeof reader.result)
                annotationsObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(reader.result))
                console.log(annotationsObject)
                console.log(typeof annotationsObject)
            };
            reader.readAsText(this.files[0])

        }
        })
```

Comment: JSON, Javascript Object Notation, **is always** a string. If it's an *object*, then it's not a string in Javascript Object Notation, it's just a plain object.

Comment: thanks.Cant I convert that into javascript object? Thought JSON.parse will do that for me

Comment: What are the two `typeof` `console.log()`s telling you?

Comment: both telling me its a string.

Comment: Why are you calling `JSON.stringify()` on a string?

Comment: JSON.parse() throws me a error.

Comment: If `JSON.parse` is throwing an error, that's telling you the string is not well-formed JSON.

Comment: It might help if you edit the question to include the error you are getting from `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently using

```
annotationsObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(reader.result))
```

But `reader.result` is already a `string` - calling `stringify` on it doesn't make any sense. Your output will just be your input, the string. Instead, parse *just* the string, without stringifying first:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      console.log(typeof reader.result)
      annotationsObject = JSON.parse(reader.result);
      console.log(annotationsObject)
      console.log(typeof annotationsObject)
    };
    reader.readAsText(this.files[0])
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Comment: *"Your output will just be your input"*. I don't think that's true. It will escape the quotes and make a quoted string, which when you `JSON.parse` it gives you back the original string. This is why both `typeof` calls return `string`.

Comment: Yeah, wording wasn't that precise, I meant that `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(reader.result))` will just return the initial `reader.result`